# Lizards probability

Tags: probability, likelihood

I am trying to learn basic probability and I would like to get the answer of the questions below. I honestly have no idea on how to even start solving it. Could someone show me or give me some advice on how to tackle it?

Wild lizards are found in a particular mountain range in Australia at an abundance of 1.4 per 6 square miles. The standard deviation of lizard abundance is 0.4 per 5 squares miles. Assume that lizard abundance is a random variable that has a bell-shaped distribution.

a. If you pick a random 12 square mile area in this mountain range, what is the likelihood that there are more than 7 lizards in this area?

b. If you pick a random 5 square mile area in this mountain range, what is the likelihood that there are between 1 and 3 lizards in this particular 5 square mile area?

Comment: (+1) This is not an elementary question because a correct solution requires understanding how the standard deviation of the mean of a spatial process changes with the support of the mean. (I would somewhat cynically guess that the intended answer pays no attention to this critical issue.) If this is a typical exercise from your source, I warmly recommend learning basic probability from a different one. Please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+book) for references.